# How to add higher video resolution in Ubuntu 10.04 (UNR on EEE1101HA)

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, resolution, eee-pc, ubuntu-netbook-remix

**UBUNTU 10.10 is out .. and the ASUS 1101HA still won't display 1366x768 on the LCD.** 
Time to wipe the UBUNTU partition, expand the WIN7 partitions and pass the machine to a windows user..

---

I picked up an ASUS EEE 1101HA with Windows 7 and installed UBUNTU 10.04 Netbook Remix (dual boot).

Ubuntu runs fine, but it doesn't recognize that the notebook LCD is 1366x768 and thus only offers 1024x768 and 800x600 as monitor resolution.

So .. how can I tell it about that higher resolution?

(Have root pwd & vi, una-bash-ed to use both.. )

**UPDATE**

there is currently (early May 2010) no video-driver for the Intel GMA500 "Poulsbo" 
**=>** no solution exists for now.

**UPDATE II** xorg.conf, created with `sudo Xorg -configure`  **removed, too long, no feedback**

**UPDATE III** using cvt and xrandr as per adamgmetzler's suggestion (doesn't work)

note that 1366 is not a multiple of 8, so cvt silently 'upgraded' to 1368

```
lexu@eee1101:~$ cvt 1366 768 60
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync


lexu@eee1101:~$ xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

lexu@eee1101:~$ xrandr --addmode "default" "1368x768_60.00"
```

after doing this I can select the new resolution, but get an error message: 
`could not set configuration for CRTC 262`

Comment: I think you meant 10.04 :)

Comment: Can we see your x configuration file?

Comment: @George Edison: You are right .. edited! I'll gladly show my X configuration file .. but I can't seem to find it. I expected Xorg.conf in /etc/X11 .. but the configuration works differently than I seem to remember!

Comment: xorg.conf (/etc/X11/xorg.conf) is dynamically generated in Ubuntu 9.10 and later.  if you create one manually, it will be used, otherwise everything's auto-detected and auto-configured.

Comment: I posted an equivalent question http://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UBUNTU 10.10 is out .. and the ASUS 1101HA still won't display 1366x768 on the LCD.
Time to wipe the UBUNTU partition, expand the WIN7 partitions and pass the machine to a windows user..

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit problematic at the moment. 9.10 worked pretty well with the GMA500 Graphics but 10.04 doesn't *yet*. Relevant threads are:

[Ubuntu Netbook Hardware Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#Asus%20Eee%201101HA) and
[Hardware Support GMA500](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo/)

Comment: Sigh, I'd read about problems with "Poulsbo" but didn't understand the relevance. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use 'cvt' command to calculate the modeline of the desired resolution and refresh rate and feed that to 'xrandr --newmode  ' then 'xrandr --addmode  ' (I might have them backwords, but it will only work if you do it in the right order with xrandr, e.g. "newmode then addmode or addmode then newmode"). This method will work when the video driver does not support a resolution fully.

Answer (score 0):

That CRTC error seems related to ~/.config/monitors.xml.  But this file seems to be created & refreshed by the system; it appears that as long as Lucid is not convinced the display can handle the requested resolution, it will edit away any changes made to this .xml-file and produce this CRTC error?
Who knows how to overrule this and permanently change the ~/.config/monitors.xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
~$ xrandr
~$ cvt 1366 768 60
~$ xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1368x768_60.00"
~$ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1368x768_60.00"
```

solved my problem